# Determining results for the carry out and sum operations on 8-bit operands

Tags: digital-logic

The problems I'm trying to solve are these:

> Determine the values for the carry `C8 C7 C6 C5 C4 C3 C2 C1`, given 
>   `A7 A6 A5 A4 A3 A2 A1 A0 = 0000 1011` and 
>   `B7 B6 B5 B4 B3 B2 B1 B0 = 0110 1011`.

Out of the possible solutions below, I picked the 2nd (marked with {}):

```
  0000 0000
{ 0000 1011 }
  1101 0000
  0010 1100
```

I chose number 2 because I carried addition `0000 1011 + 0110 1011` and the carry is `0000 1011`.

Is my solution correct?

The other problem is this:

> Determine the values for the sum `S7 S6 S5 S4 S3 S2 S1 S0`, given 
>   `A7 A6 A5 A4 A3 A2 A1 A0 = 0000 1100` and 
>   `B7 B6 B5 B4 B3 B2 B1 B0 = 1111 1010`.

```
  0011 0000
  1111 1010
  0110 0000
{ 0000 0110 }
```

I chose number 4 because I carried addition `0000 1100 + 1111 1010` and the sum is `0000 0110`.

Are my solutions correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your work looks exactly correct to me.